# How to hide mysqli null row

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have the following code and i need to hide area2 and adsec2 if in my mysql table are empty.

here is my code

```
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultFilmCerts)) {
            echo "\t<tr><td>".$row['pn']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['careerin']."</td><td>".$row['careerout']."</td><td>".$row['area1']."-".$row['adsec1']."<br>".$row['area2']."-".$row['adsec2']."</td><td>View <i>thematic </i>career</td></tr>\n";
        }
```

Comment: then use a conditional `empty()` or IS NULL.

Comment: `.$row['area2'].` becomes then `.( !empty( $row['area2'] ) ? $row['area2'] : ''  ).`

Comment: Thanks @b.enoit.be, I deleted my answer that you replied on. I did not fully understand what was being asked so my answer was wrong.

Comment: i think b.enoit.be that this is correct. Just one thing. How to hide also <br> if there is no other row?

Answer (score 0):

check for null.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultFilmCerts)) {

```
$area1 = ($row["area1"] == null ? "" : $row["area1"]);
$adsec1 = ($row["adsec1"] == null ? "" : $row["adsec1"]);
```

add these two lines above your echo statement.

```
echo "\t<tr><td>".$row['pn']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['careerin']."</td><td>".$row['careerout']."</td><td>".$area1."-".$adsec1."<br>".$row['area2']."-".$row['adsec2']."</td><td>View <i>thematic </i>career</td></tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply relation between your tables. Then use LEFT JOIN.
  In received data from query, hide td (with colspan if necessary) if value is null or unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

i hope it will help you..With the of this you can count the numbers of rows from database.

```
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); if($rowcount>0){ //diplasy your data}else{  }
```